# Graphing sets that contain logical connectives

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The task it to graph:
$\{(x, y) \in\ \mathbb R^2 | (x^2+y^2 > 1) \implies [(x^2+y^2 \le 2) \land (\lnot (xy=0) \implies |y|=|x|] ) ] \}$

I managed to solve a problem that was similar to this but simpler, I did it by considering all the cases but this one is more complicated and I'm not sure how I should tackle it.

Comment: I think that the set is not well defined or lacks clearity. I mean, it is not clear that $(x^2+y^2>1)$ must hold for all $(x,y)$ or if it is an **if** statement, i.e. if $x^2+y^2>1$ then...

Comment: I.e., the implication is satisfied by any pair (x,y) for which (x^2+y^2 >1) is false, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $p \Rightarrow q$ is the same as $\neg p \vee q$ we can write the set as
$$
S = \{(x, y) \in\ \mathbb R^2 \mid (x^2+y^2 \le 1) \vee [(x^2+y^2 \le 2) \land (xy=0 \vee |y|=|x|)] \} \\
= B(1) \cup (B(2) \cap (C_+ \cup C_\times ))
$$
where $B(r)$ is the closed disc with origin $0$ and radius $r$,
$C_+$ are the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$ (the axis cross) and 
$C_\times$ are the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$.

[image: rendition]

Comment: Nice interpretation! How'd you draw the graphic? (what software was used?)

Comment: What version of GeoGebra are you using? I hadn't used the software for over a year and a half (I have geogebra 4, I think), and it seems it it may not be compatible on Windows 10?

Comment: This was GeoGebra 5.0.279.0-3D on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: I updated the image, after I got aware of a mistake.